# Probability your opponent has a pocket pair when you are paired versus not

Tags: probability

If I am holding a pocket pair does that effect the probability my opponent has a pocket pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you have a pocket pair the probability your opponent has a pocket pair goes up slightly.  You basically have less blockers.

you have pair the opponent = combin(4;2) * 12 + 1 = 73 = 5.959184%

you don't have a pair the opponent = combin(4:2) * 11 + 2 * combin(3;2) = 72 = 5.877551%

So the probability goes up 1/72 if you hold a pocket pair

Answer (score 0):

When **not** holding a pocket pair:

```
((4 choose 2) * 11 + (3 choose 2) * 2) / (50 choose 2) = 5.87755%
```

When holding a pocket pair

```
((4 choose 2) * 12 + (2 choose 2) * 1) / (50 choose 2) = 5.95918%
```

So your opponent has a slightly *better*  chance of getting a pocket pair when you hold one yourself, but the difference is indeed slight!

Comment: I think you have **not** backwards.

Comment: Let me take a look

Comment: You're correct @paparazo, thanks for pointing this out.  The post has been edited correspondingly

Comment: Did you down vote my answer?

Comment: I did, it does not seem clear to me how you derived your answer, nor does it seem to be correct.  I will be happy to remove my down-vote if you make it more clear, and correct the mistakes.

Comment: Fixed.  In summary when you had an I error I gave you a polite comment and did not vote down.  You vote down with no comment.  Can use your down votes as you chose.  Not arguing.